# How to optimize this piece of code?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have the following piece of code:

```
    protected StoreDetailModel GetSelectedStore()
    {
        if (StoresWithDepartmentType != null && StoresWithDepartmentType.Any())
        {
            StoreDetailModel currentUserStore = WebsiteContext.GetCurrentUserStore();

            if (currentUserStore != null && currentUserStore.Item != null)
            {
                StoreDetailModel store = 
                   StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID ==    
                                                 currentUserStore.Item.ID);
                if (store == null)
                {
                    store = StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
                }
                return store;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Too many ifs make this code hardly readable. How can I optimize it and make it clearer?

Comment: It's more a question for codereview.

Comment: More of a question for code review.. however I would not say that code was unreadable to be honest.

Comment: Depending on whether the null refs are expected or not one could instead throw exceptions and centralize the error handling.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Looks like a codebase that suffers from a case of the null-disease.  Very hard to cure.  What is the point of starting a shopping web site that has no stores?  Why would you let a user navigate to a page without a store?  Remove the null checks, now you can fix the real bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write

```
return StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID == currentUserStore.Item.ID) ?? StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
```

instead of

```
 StoreDetailModel store = 
               StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID ==    
                                             currentUserStore.Item.ID);
            if (store == null)
            {
                store = StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
            }
            return store;
```

but some people don't like that. Ifs are necessary by the look of it, they don't bother me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expecting to return the current users store or null if one cannot be found.  It can be simplified as follows.

```
protected StoreDetailModel GetSelectedStore()
{
    if (StoresWithDepartmentType == null) return null; // There are no stores

    // Get the user store or return the first available store
    StoreDetailModel currentUserStore = WebsiteContext.GetCurrentUserStore();
    return currentUserStore ?? StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
}
```

If there are no stores to lookup, then nothing can be returned.

Otherwise return the user's store, or If user's store cannot be found, then the first available can be returned.

The simplification works because the lookup on `StoresWithDepartmentType` appears to return the same object.

Comment: But in `return currentUserStore` I will get `currentUserStore` but I need `StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID ==    
                                              currentUserStore.Item.ID)` ...

Comment: @zoidbergDr What is the difference between the `StoreDetailModel` returned by `WebsiteContext.GetCurrentUserStore()` and `StoreWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault()`?  They appear to be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to nest if-blocks, so i flatted structure for readability.

Line of last 'return' statement comes from the answer of artm.

```
protected StoreDetailModel GetSelectedStore()
{
    if (StoresWithDepartmentType == null || !StoresWithDepartmentType.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    StoreDetailModel currentUserStore = WebsiteContext.GetCurrentUserStore();
    if (currentUserStore == null || currentUserStore.Item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID == currentUserStore.Item.ID) ?? StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd split it up into a number of well-named methods.

This won't compile (because I don't know all the types you're using) but hopefully it will give you the idea:

```
protected StoreDetailModel GetSelectedStore()
{
    if (anyStoresWithDepartmentType())
        return storeWithCurrentlySelectedItem();

    return null;
}

private bool anyStoresWithDepartmentType()
{
    return (StoresWithDepartmentType != null) && StoresWithDepartmentType.Any();
}

private StoreDetailModel storeWithCurrentlySelectedItem()
{
    var itemId = currentUserStoreItemId();

    if (itemId == null)
        return null;

    return storeWithItem(itemId);
}

private StoreItemId currentUserStoreItemId()
{
    StoreDetailModel currentUserStore = WebsiteContext.GetCurrentUserStore();

    if (currentUserStore != null && currentUserStore.Item != null)
        return currentUserStore.Item.ID;

    return null;
}

private StoreDetailModel storeWithItem(StoreItemId itemId)
{
    StoreDetailModel store = StoresWithDepartmentType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID == itemId);

    if (store != null)
        return store;

    return StoresWithDepartmentType.First();
}
```